# Sharepoint (Enterprise) works on other Laptops but not in mine

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, access-denied

In the company where I work we usually use our own Laptops and the company have Sharepoint, in my old Laptop a DELL everithing works fine, but in the new one a HP Pavillon, I can access fine but alwas appear a message: "This site is read only at the moment dua a maintenance".

Also trying to fill a form, in the old laptop works fine but in new one says i don't have privileges.

I'm using same user/password in both laptops and bot are connected to the company network.

Technical Support on my work doesn't have any clue.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks and Regards